# Telerik RadTreeListView Event binding

Tags: silverlight, xaml, telerik

I am currently working on a Telerik Silverlight Control, the RadTreeListView.
Is it possible to bind a DoubleClick Event to this control? Please note that I'am using
MVVM pattern and that the RadTreeListView isn't equal to the RadTreeView control.
It would be nice if anyone can share his experience with me.

I tried many ways, but nothing worked..

Last example (look at the command):

```
<telerik:RadTreeListView x:Name="TreeListControl" 
                             AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                             IsReadOnly="True"
                             ItemsSource="{Binding TreeViewData, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
                             IsExpandedBinding="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}"
                             CanUserFreezeColumns="False"
                             RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed"
                             ColumnWidth="*"
                             CanUserSortColumns="False"
                             evt:MouseDoubleClick.Command="{Binding DoubleCommand}"
                             >
```

Helper Class:

```
.... public static class MouseDoubleClick
{
    public static DependencyProperty CommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Command",
            typeof(ICommand),
            typeof(MouseDoubleClick),
            new PropertyMetadata(CommandChanged));

    public static DependencyProperty CommandParameterProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("CommandParameter",
            typeof(object),
            typeof(MouseDoubleClick),
            new PropertyMetadata(null)); ....
```

The compiler gives out the error:

```
Error   3   The property 'Command' does not exist on the type 'RadTreeListView' in the XML namespace 'clr-namespace:CombinationTreeViewControl'.    C:\Users\B95703\Documents\Entwicklung\Silverlight\SilverlightComponents\CombinationTreeViewControl\View\CombinationTreeViewControl.xaml 32  34  CombinationTreeViewControl
```

Best regards
Patrik

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using PropertyMetaData in your RegisteredAttached() methods, try using UIPropertyMetaData.

Also see my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13886760/430897

Answer (score 0):

Try using System.Windows.Interactivity Triggers on your TreeListView on the Click event:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers><i:EventTrigger EventName="DoubleClick">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.TreeViewDoubleClickCommand, ElementName=LayoutRoot}"
                                       CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem,ElementName=MyTreeView}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Considering that the DoubleClick event is exposed in the TreeListView control.

Answer (score 0):

you can use of RowsIsexpandedChange.when expanding changing, you can use of variable isexpand.

```
   private ICommand _rowIsExpandedChangedClick;
    public ICommand RowIsExpandedChangedClick
    {

        get
        {
            if (_rowIsExpandedChangedClick == null)
            {
                _rowIsExpandedChangedClick = new MVVM.DelegateCommand<Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.RowEventArgs>(RowIsExpandedChangedClickShow);
            }

            return _rowIsExpandedChangedClick;
        }
        set { _rowIsExpandedChangedClick = value; }
    }
    RadTreeListView _currentRadTreeListView;
    private void RowIsExpandedChangedClickShow(Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.RowEventArgs e)
    {

        var folder = e.Row.DataContext as YourClass;
       var  row = e.Row as GridViewRow;
       _currentRadTreeListView = e.OriginalSource as RadTreeListView;
        if (row.IsExpanded)
        {
            folder.Isexpanded = row.IsExpanded;
        }



    }

  //----------------------------------------ExpandHierarchyItem for expand specialitems
  private void collapseorexpand(FolderSarfasl _currntfolder)
  {
      if(_currntfolder.Isexpanded==true)
          if(_currentRadTreeListView!=null)
            _currentRadTreeListView.ExpandHierarchyItem(_currntfolder);
      for (int i = 0; i < _currntfolder.SubFolders.Count; i++)
      {
          collapseorexpand(_currntfolder.SubFolders[i]);
      }
  }
```